# Extract results from a list in R

Tags: r, list, machine-learning, data-extraction

I have a list called *bag*. It is the result of a number of regression methods from [mlr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlr/) package (Pseudo-)code is shown below. I want to extract the aggregated performance results from it **for each *Task***. For instance, how can I access to both "Aggr. perf" values from $visc.1$regr.rpart and $visc.2$regr.rpart.  I can access them individually, but I think there must be a simpler approach.

```
> class(bag)

[1] "list"
```

Code producing bag (dataset is not included):

```
library('mlr')
dataset = read.csv("dataset.csv")
regr.task = makeRegrTask(id = "dataset", data = dataset, target = "target")
# feature reduction
fv = generateFilterValuesData(regr.task)

# resampling description    
rdesc = makeResampleDesc("Holdout")

####################
bag = NULL
####################

for (i in 1:2)
{

  cols = c(order(fv$data$randomForestSRC.rfsrc, decreasing = TRUE)[1:i], ncol(dataset))
  dataset.ig = dataset[, cols]
  iid = paste(c("dataset", i), collapse = ".")
  regr.task = makeRegrTask(id = iid,
                           data = dataset.ig,
                           target = "dataset")

  # learners
  lrns = list(
    "regr.bcart"
    ,"regr.fnn"
    ,"regr.rpart"
  )

      set.seed(0, "L'Ecuyer")
      bmr = benchmark(lrns, regr.task, rdesc, show.info = FALSE)

      #########################
      bag = c(bag, bmr)
      #########################
}
```

MWC:

```
for (i in seq(1,42,3))
{
    print (bag[i]$results)
}
```

Output:

```
$visc.1
$visc.1$regr.bcart
Resample Result
Task: visc.1
Learner: regr.bcart
Aggr perf: mse.test.mean=5.14e+03
Runtime: 0.181672

$visc.1$regr.cforest
Resample Result
Task: visc.1
Learner: regr.cforest
Aggr perf: mse.test.mean=4.92e+03
Runtime: 0.103091

$visc.1$regr.fnn
Resample Result
Task: visc.1
Learner: regr.fnn
Aggr perf: mse.test.mean=2.44e+03
Runtime: 0.0151947

$visc.1$regr.mars
Resample Result
Task: visc.1
Learner: regr.mars
Aggr perf: mse.test.mean=3.77e+03
Runtime: 0.0163326

$visc.1$regr.rpart
Resample Result
Task: visc.1
Learner: regr.rpart
Aggr perf: mse.test.mean=4.77e+03
Runtime: 0.0265007


$visc.2
$visc.2$regr.bcart
Resample Result
Task: visc.2
Learner: regr.bcart
Aggr perf: mse.test.mean=5.14e+03
Runtime: 0.177014

$visc.2$regr.cforest
Resample Result
Task: visc.2
Learner: regr.cforest
Aggr perf: mse.test.mean=4.95e+03
Runtime: 0.115235

$visc.2$regr.fnn
Resample Result
Task: visc.2
Learner: regr.fnn
Aggr perf: mse.test.mean=3.25e+03
Runtime: 0.0116491

$visc.2$regr.mars
Resample Result
Task: visc.2
Learner: regr.mars
Aggr perf: mse.test.mean=2.67e+03
Runtime: 0.0153017

$visc.2$regr.rpart
Resample Result
Task: visc.2
Learner: regr.rpart
Aggr perf: mse.test.mean=4.77e+03
Runtime: 0.0252295
```

**EDIT:**
I have also saved dput(bag[1:2]) [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpysc4hjg8y8u4d/dput.txt?dl=0).

Comment: Please use `dput` to show a smal reproducible example

Comment: Do you mean to use dput instead of print? It produces much more results.

Comment: As it is a list, it is better to have only a couple of list elements i.e `dput(bag[1:2])` and what do you want to extract i.e. your expected output

Comment: Ok. I am producing it.

Comment: I have uploaded dput(bag[1:2]) here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpysc4hjg8y8u4d/dput.txt?dl=0

Comment: No. `dput` it in your question. Don't add external links

Comment: It is a large file! SO does not permit me more than 64k characters

Comment: I added the code that is used to produce bag. why downvote? :(

Answer (score 0):

creating a list from `mtcars` columns as per `bag` example above.

```
io <-list(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl, mtcars$disp)
names(io) <- c("mpg","cyl","disp")
class(io)
[1] "list"

io
$mpg
 [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5
[22] 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4

$cyl
 [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4

$disp
 [1] 160.0 160.0 108.0 258.0 360.0 225.0 360.0 146.7 140.8 167.6 167.6 275.8 275.8 275.8 472.0 460.0 440.0
[18]  78.7  75.7  71.1 120.1 318.0 304.0 350.0 400.0  79.0 120.3  95.1 351.0 145.0 301.0 121.0
```

For implementing **MWC**:

```
req_rows <- seq(1,length(io$mpg),3)
req_rows
[1]  1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31


# rather than using loop, use this
io$mpg[io_seq]
[1] 21.0 21.4 14.3 19.2 17.3 10.4 30.4 15.5 19.2 30.4 15.0
```

Comment: How can I get the Agg. perf. from both $visc.1$regr.rpart and $visc.2$regr.rpart?

Comment: @remo, can you give the `function` used for getting `bag` ie. `bag <- mlr::some_function()` so that an example can be reproduced, even adding `str(bag)` will help

Comment: I have added a simplified version of the code. Why downvote? :(